# javascript using window["my_func"]() inside window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

OK I have looked for a solution to this and have failed, if i have missed a post here please point me to it.

Problem: I understand that using eval to convert a string to a function is considered bad practice e.g.

```
eval("my_func"());
```

From what I have found the correct way is to use window object e.g.

```
window["my_func"]();
```

This works absolutley fine except for when I need it inside a window listener e.g.

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  function my_func(){
    alert("hi");
  }
  window["my_func"]();
});
```

It gives the error of "Uncaught TypeError: window.my_func is not a function"

I tried using the "this" keyword instead of window but no joy, I've tried not using an arrow function to no joy, I can still use eval but it is not best practice, not sure where to go here.

Any ideas?

cheers

Zen

Comment: `my_func` is not global here, you've to place that function definition to the global scope. Though much simpler would be just call `my_func();`.

Comment: Assign an object to a constant inside the function you pass to `addEventListener`. Make the function a property of that object. Use that object instead of `window`.